# To print result of sql query without braces in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'am leaner of node.js and I just know some basics of javascript,Sorry if I went wrong.

To print result retrieved by sql query in node.js,I tried using

```
   <p>Users are " + util.inspect(results) + ".</p>"
```

and I also tried using

```
      var out = JSON.stringify(results);
      <p> Users are " + out + ".</p>"
```

This both are resulting like:

```
             Users are [ { name: 'manohar' }, { name: 'bhai' } ]
```

My doubt is how can I print them like

```
          Manohar 
          bhai
```

And my db.js code is:

```
        var http = require("http");
        var port = 3000;
        var serverUrl = "localhost";
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var util = require('util');
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({

               host : 'localhost',
               user : 'xxxxxxxx',
               password: 'xxxxxxx',
               database: "wst"

          });

         var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
             connection.query('select * from welcome',function(err, results, fields){
             var html = "<p> Users are " + util.inspect(results) + "</p> <br/>";
             res.end(html);

          });

      });



         console.log("Listening at " + serverUrl + ":" + port);

         server.listen(port, serverUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know node, but try:

```
...
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   connection.query('select * from welcome',function(err, results, fields){
   var html;
   if (results.length > 0) {
      html = "<p> Users are ";
      for (var i in results) {
         html += i.name + "<br />";
      }
   } else {
      // no users found
   }
   html += "</p>";
   util.puts(html);
   res.end(html);

});
...
```

util.inspect is used to stringifies javascript object.